# Processing a large SQL query in Python using Pandas?

Tags: python, postgresql, pandas, dataframe, bigdata

I would like to back-test some data which will be pulled from a Postgres database, using Python, psycopg2 and Pandas.

The data which will be pulled from Postgres is very large (over 10Gbs) - my system will not be able to hold this in terms of RAM, even if a Pandas data frame is able to store this much data.

As an overview, I expect my Python program will need to do the following:

1: Connect to a remote (LAN based) Postgres database server

2: Run a basic select query against a database table

3: Store the result of the query in a Pandas data frame

4: Perform calculation operations on the data within the Pandas data frame

5: Write the result of these operations back to an existing table within the database.

I expect the data that will be returned in step 2 will be very large.

Is it possible to stream the result of a large query to a Pandas data frame, so that my Python script can process data in smaller chunks, say of 1gb, as an example?

Any ideas, suggestions or resources you can point to, on how best to do this, or if I am not approaching this in the right way, will be much appreciated, and I am sure that this will be useful to others going forward.

Thank you.

Comment: It depends... What kind of operations are you going to do in Pandas with that data? Can all of those operations work with chunks or do you need to have them all processed in RAM (for example sorting, groupping, etc.)? In this case you can consider using Dask DataFrame or even Apache Spark (in cluster mode)

Comment: Thanks for your comment - the operations will calculate moving averages and other similar calculations, so these can be done in chucks... But I need to understand how I can get data in chunks from the database - I was hoping I could find away to query and stream the first 10000 rows, process that, then receive and process the next 10000 rows and so on... I will check out Dask DataFrame and Apache Spark - thanks for mentioning them!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Demo - how to read data from SQL DB in chunks and process single chunks:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

# conn = create_engine('postgresql://user:password@host:port/dbname')
conn = create_engine('postgresql+psycopg2://user:password@host:port/dbname')

qry = "select * from table where ..."
sql_reader = pd.read_sql(qry, con=conn, chunksize=10**4)

for df in sql_reader:
    # process `df` (chunk of 10.000 rows) here
```

**UPDATE:** [very good point from @jeremycg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47075300/processing-a-large-sql-query-in-python-using-pandas/47077999?noredirect=1#comment81104699_47077999)

> depending on the exact setup, OP might also need to use
>   `conn.dialect.server_side_cursors = True` and
>   `conn.execution_options(stream_results = True)` as the database driver
>   will otherwise fetch all the results locally, then stream them to
>   python in chunks

Comment: depending on the exact setup, OP might also need to use `conn.dialect.server_side_cursors = True` and `conn.execution_options(stream_results = True)` as the database driver will otherwise fetch all the results locally, then stream them to python in chunks

Comment: @jeremycg, good point - thank you! I'll add your comment to an answer as it is...